# Convert collection of N items into N collections of 1 item each?

Tags: java

In Java is there an easy/convenient way to convert a collection of N items into N collections each with one item?  I mean other than manually going through each item in the collection and copy it into a new collection.

Comment: Sure. [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and has an [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) method. All implementations provide a no-argument constructor.  Nothing else seems to be required to accomplish your task. Does it have any practical purpose?

Comment: Well, since your N collections will have to be placed in a collection of some sort, it seems like you could just look at what you have and declare "Done!"

Comment: This question has spawned a [question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57873/31503).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with one statement in Java 8.  `l1` is some `Collection<T>`, and the result is a `List<ArrayList<T>>` where each `ArrayList<T>` contains one element from the collection.

```
List<ArrayList<T>> l2 = l1.stream().map(x -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Broken down, this:

- Creates a `Stream` of all elements from the collection;
- Maps each element to an `ArrayList` that contains that element;
- Collects the resulting `ArrayList`s into a `List<ArrayList>`.

Comment: In case OP does not know: such code will work in Java 8 only.

Comment: I'm still stuck with Java 6.  But it's nice to learn what's newly possible in Java 8.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use guava, you could have a [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) < E, List< E >> that looks like:

```
public final class ItemToListFunction<E> implements Function<E, List<E>>
{
    public List<E> apply(E input)
    {
        //if it does not need to be mutable
        return Collections.singletonList(input);

        //if it does need to be mutable
        final List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
        list.add(input);
        return list;
    }
}
```

You can then use one of the transform methods in [Collections2](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html), [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html), or [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html).
The advantage of this approach is that the creation of the internal lists is deferred until actual iteration over the elements.

Comment: I can only use standard Java 6 constructs.  But it's nice to know the alternatives.  Thanks.